# Remote Viewing of Certificates as a Non-admin

Tags: remote-access, mmc, limited-access

Does anyone know how to view certificates remotely from another machine without granting that user admin. rights? I am using the MMC certificates snap-in to view a remote machine. The remote machine can be connected to without issue, but when I attempt to even view the certificate stores it gives me this error:

[image]

Any idea how to grant a user the ability to view without giving them unnecessary rights?

Comment: It appears your user profile has not been given the required permissions to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, most certainly. I am trying to figure out what permissions I need without granting full administrator access. None of the default groups under local users and groups fix this issue, so I might need to do some registry editing.